# Using Fabric cdn in offline mode

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, react-native, fabricjs

i'm working with `react native` Interacting with `html canvas`, helped by
`fabric.js`.

Example:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="margin-top:8px; margin-left:8px" width="290px" height="250px"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
   preserveObjectStacking: true,
});
</script>
```

To make this interaction, i'm using `react-native-webview-bridge` and so far I have not had any problems with this implementation.

Right now, my application needs to work in ***offline mode*** and one of the things i must endure is just the functionality of the `canvas`.

Although the idea I had at the beginning seemed simple, eventually complicated.

> The idea was to copy all the cdn it was using to local scripts and load them as paths.

At first it worked perfect, but only in debug mode. When I test it in release mode it does not work :(

**CODE:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-xxxxx/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.js'></script>
```

**Code for OFFLINE MODE:**

```
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-xxxxx/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='./Scripts/fabric.js'></script>
```

> the `Code for OFFLINE MODE:` is the one that will be left for both online and offline

When i try to load `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.js` as locally path the canvas never loads the text I'm trying to add with the following fabric function.

**PDTA: This is not working even in online mode. It only works if I link to cdn directly**

```
var text = new fabric.Text(props, {
    fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro',
    fontSize: fontSize,
    selectable: false,
    fill: 'rgb(151,151,151)',
    top: top,
    left: left
});
text.type = "imagesSet";
canvas.add(text);
```

*The questions are:*

**- Why does it work in debug but not in release mode?**

**- Does it make sense what i'm trying to do? Or definitively it is impossible because the cdn of fabric.js uses certain scripts that can only be executed in online mode**

[GITHUB topic](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2202)

Thanks in advance for reading and any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Using `cache manifest` i can solve the problem, but only when the app is open and goes to offline mode.

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2202

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

**I still can not find a way to support when the application closes and it opens in offline mode**

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded? Try removing this, as there's no need to check the integrity of an offline local file...integrity="sha256-xxxxx/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"

Comment: maybe try to remove the crossOrigin attribute since now you are loading from same source.

Comment: hi guys. thanks for answering. Unfortunately none of these ideas worked for me. `Xogle` i already confirmed that jquery is loading correctly

Comment: Have you checked browser network tab is fabric.js makes external calls ? to some other websites ?

Comment: I am not getting what is your exact issue, can you run [this](http://www.mediafire.com/file/rvh813kubopz7it/fabricjs.zip) and check? I have local file(v-1.7.3) and have a text object and it works.

Comment: Why don't you install fabricjs through npm *(or any other library for that matter)*? That'd be the **ideal** way and has an increasing chance of working.

Comment: @jose920405 There should not be any issues in loading the files locally. I do not think that your problem is with loading fabric/jquery. I have set up a small demo, as close to your code as possible, with just fabric and jquery, loaded from local files, running on a local webserver without breakout and I can add text to canvas without any problems,. Note that I did not use React. Are you able to share more code?